# How do you convert a pandas column to time with milisecond?

Tags: python, pandas, time, series, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe column that pandas currently thinks is an object. It's written as "58:42.5" which is the minutes then seconds and fractions of a second. I want to convert that to a time type so that I can subtract the two time columns I have to get a duration.

I've tried:
`merged['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['started_at'],format='%M:%S').dt.time`

However, that returns an error saying that the .5 was not converted. (ValueError: unconverted data remains: .5). I can I convert my entire two columns of time data to the correct format so that I can eventually do math with them.

My columns look like:

> started_at ,  ended_at
>
> 58:42.5    ,  00:02.3
>
> 00:55.5    ,  02:13.9

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `.%f` would convert the microseconds.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue - output `0    00:58:42.500000; 1    00:00:55.500000`

Comment: This is a non-issue, please read the [to_datetime doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). And clearly the reason `pd.to_datetime(...,format='%M:%S.%f')` hiccups on '4/27/2018 2:55' is because you missed the m/d/Y format='%m/%d/%Y %M:%S.%f'. The error is telling you so.

Comment: @kaecvtionr: no, I read the entire post three times before I responded and it doesn't say that anywhere. There is nothing about different formats when you get to rows like row 30,000. Please edit the missing information into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to `timedelta` without specifying a format:

```
x = '58:42.5'

res = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+x)

Timedelta('0 days 00:58:42.500000')
```

This transformation can easily be applied to a series:

```
merged['started_at'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + merged['started_at'], errors='coerce')
```

Your subsequent operations, for example difference between `timedelta` objects, should follow naturally.

Comment: @kaecvtionr, sorry updated - should be `timedelta`, not `datetime`.

Comment: So the timedelta, threw up an error so I'm guessing in the 60k rows of data there some row that does not match this format. Is there a way to ignore the rows that don't match the format?

Comment: @kaecvtionr, Sure you can add `errors='coerce'` (see updated code) which will give `NaT` when conversion is not possible. You can then use `fillna` to fill with some default timedelta value.

Comment: Thanks for your help JPP. So the reason I was doing the above was so I could calculate the duration of an array of events. It converted correctly, but there are occasionally logic errors such as the end time being before the start time. So I thought I'd write a for-loop which goes through the dataframe and adds an hour, which is below but I get a KeyError: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:02.300000'). any ideas? thx for your help

for i in merged['ended_at']:
    while merged['ended_at'][i]<merged['started_at'][i]:
            merged['ended_at'][i] = merged['ended_at'][i]+timedelta(hours=1)

Comment: @kaecvtionr, You shouldn't have to write a `for` loop if your data is clean. But it appears it's not, so unless I can see a specific problem input it's difficult to advise.